# Nest two workflows in a single workflow to run parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, workflow, powershell-4.0

I am sure I'm not the first person to try this but can't find a single post about it.

I am attempting to nest two workflows inside of a single workflow so the two workflows function in parallel and I get 10 processes. Here is what I tried first:

```
Workflow a {
    param(
        [parameter()]alist
    )
    sequence
    {
        $WORKFLOW:aOutput = @()
        foreach ($aObject in $aList)
        {
            $WORKFLOW:aOutput += do_stuff
        }
        return $WORKFLOW:aOutput
    }
)
}
Workflow b {
    param(
        [parameter()]blist
    )
    sequence
    {
        $WORKFLOW:bOutput = @()
        foreach ($bObject in $bList)
        {
            $WORKFLOW:bOutput += do_stuff
        }
        return $WORKFLOW:bOutput
    }
)
}
Workflow nest
{
param(
    [parameter()]alist,
    [parameter()]blist
)
parallel
{
    $aOutput = b -alist alist
    $bOutput = b -blist blist
}
return ($aOutput,$bOutput)
}
```

This all works great but only spins up 5 parallel processes instead of 10. So I attempted this:

```
Workflow nest
{
param(
    [parameter()]alist,
    [parameter()]blist
)
parallel
{
    $aOutput =  inlinescript
    {
        Workflow a {
        param(
            [parameter()]alist
        )
        sequence
        {
            $WORKFLOW:aOutput = @()
            foreach ($aObject in $aList)
            {
                $WORKFLOW:aOutput += do_stuff
            }
            return $WORKFLOW:aOutput
        }
    }
    $bOutput = inlinescript
    {
        Workflow b {
                param(
                    [parameter()]blist
                )
                sequence
                {
                    $WORKFLOW:bOutput = @()
                    foreach ($bObject in $bList)
                    {
                        $WORKFLOW:bOutput += do_stuff
                    }
                    return $WORKFLOW:bOutput
                }
            )
        }
        b -blist blist
    }
}
return ($aOutput,$bOutput)
}
```

The issue I am having here is it throws an error for using the scope WORKFLOW inside of an inlinescript block. The error says to use the scope USING instead but I get an error when I switch to that about redefining the variable inside the foreach -parallel block.

What I am looking for is this possible and if so what scoping needs to be used to nest the workflows? Or is there another way to get the workflows to run at the same time with 5 processes each?

Apologize for pseudo code but the actual code contains information I cannot share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, and figure out where the USING scope was to be used.

```
Workflow nest
{
param(
    [parameter()]alist,
    [parameter()]blist
)
parallel
{
    $aOutput =  inlinescript
    {
        Workflow a {
        param(
            [parameter()]alist
        )
        sequence
        {
            $aOutput = foreach ($aObject in $aList)
            {
                do_stuff
            }
            return aOutput
        }
        a -alist $USING:alist
    }
    $bOutput = inlinescript
    {
        Workflow b {
                param(
                    [parameter()]blist
                )
                sequence
                {
                    $bOutput = foreach ($bObject in $bList)
                    {
                        do_stuff
                    }
                    return $bOutput
                }
            )
        }
        b -blist $USING:blist
    }
}
return ($aOutput,$bOutput)
}
```

Basically I removed the array definition that was being added to in the foreach loop and set it to equal the foreach loop. This removed my need for a scope at all. I had to set the passed a/b list variable from the nest workflow to the inlinescript with the USING scope.